# Cannot assign "id": "Product.category" must be a "CategoryProduct" instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys

i'm working on a django project and i got this error (Cannot assign "'11'": "Product.category" must be a "CategoryProduct" instance.) anyone here can help me please.

Model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nombre", max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryProduct, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='category')  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

View:

```
class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
model = Product
form_class = ProductForm
success_url = '/adminpanel/products/'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.get_form()
    category = CategoryProduct.objects.get(id=request.POST['category'])
    
    if form.is_valid():
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.category = category
        product.save()
```

Form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=150, label="Nombre")
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(obj.id, obj.name) for obj in CategoryProduct.objects.all()], label="Categoría")

class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['name', 'category']
```

Comment: Use a `ModelChoiceField`, not a `ChoiceField`, or even better is to just omit the creating of the form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can let Django's `ModelForm` do its work, this will create a [**`ModelChoiceField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), which is where the system gets stuck: it tries to assign the primary key to `category`, but that should be a `ProductCategory` object, so you can let Django handle this with:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'category']
```

If you want to specify a different label, you can use the [**`verbose_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) from the model field, or specify this in the [**`labels`** options <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) of the `Meta` of the `ProductForm`. So you can specify `Categoria` with:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        CategoryProduct,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='products',
        verbose_name='Categoria'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

then the `CreateView` can just use its boilerplate logic:

```
class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = '/adminpanel/products/'
```

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `Category` model to the `Product`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`category`</s> relation to `products`.